# converting mp4 to rtsp

Tags: python, mp4

I would like to a little help.
How can I convert mp4 to rtsp in python?
I've tried this code, which does not work - it doesn't seem to know what `gi` is.
[image]
olso geting this in the cmd
[image]
I'am using python 3.8.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import gi

gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
gi.require_version('GstRtspServer', '1.0')
from gi.repository import Gst, GstRtspServer, GObject, GLib

loop = GLib.MainLoop()
Gst.init(None)

class TestRtspMediaFactory(GstRtspServer.RTSPMediaFactory):
    def __init__(self):
        GstRtspServer.RTSPMediaFactory.__init__(self)

    def do_create_element(self, url):
        #set mp4 file path to filesrc's location property
        src_demux = "filesrc location=/path/to/dir/test.mp4 ! qtdemux name=demux"
        h264_transcode = "demux.video_0"
        #uncomment following line if video transcoding is necessary
        #h264_transcode = "demux.video_0 ! decodebin ! queue ! x264enc"
        pipeline = "{0} {1} ! queue ! rtph264pay name=pay0 config-interval=1 pt=96".format(src_demux, h264_transcode)
        print ("Element created: " + pipeline)
        return Gst.parse_launch(pipeline)

class GstreamerRtspServer():
    def __init__(self):
        self.rtspServer = GstRtspServer.RTSPServer()
        factory = TestRtspMediaFactory()
        factory.set_shared(True)
        mountPoints = self.rtspServer.get_mount_points()
        mountPoints.add_factory("/stream1", factory)
        self.rtspServer.attach(None)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = GstreamerRtspServer()
    loop.run()
```

Comment: Have you installed gi? If not you will need to do so. Could you edit your question to include the error you're getting

Answer (score 0):

The gi package is provided by https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html - install that.

As an aside, though, you seem to be on Windows; you might not have the rest of the Glib/Gstreamer ecosystem available.